# SWITCHING sockets according to FIELDS of a client POST form [ Sails node js ]

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, sails.js

In our data processing API Controller we have **CASE SWITCH** sockets according to the POST FIELDS filled in **or not filled** on the POST FORM by the client.

The question is : what is the easiest way to identify the correct CASE according to posted fields.

Say we have six different fields on the client POST FORM

Counting all possibilities that amounts to a total of 64

In Sails we are looking for the most efficient way to **mark every combination** in order to switch-case then route each one of them in the API Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you  want a bitmask. If you are running a version of Node that supports [the ES6 binary literals](http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/817/es6-everyday-binary-and-octal-literals/), you can express each combination of possibilities like this:

```
0b000000 // ===0; all options turned on
0b000001 // ===1; only the last option turned on
0b000010 // ===2; only the second-to-last option turned on
0b000011 // ===3; only the last to options turned on
...
```

This will allow you to use bitwise operators to pull out just the flags you care about in various situations. It also should be memory efficient. And you can choose to use base 10 integers in your switch statement if that's easier for you for some reason because they are equivalent to the binary literals.

Answer (score 1):

With six fields

"all options turned on" can be marked as 0b111111

and none as 0b000000